# Convert list of Python strings to vector[PyObject] in Cython

Tags: cython

I have, in Python, a list of strings that I'm looking to pass to Cython. Previously I achieved this by converting all strings to `bytes`, passing to Cython, and then converting the returned result back to `str`:

```py
# script.py
stringlist = ["one","two","three","one"]
output = func(stringlist)
```

```py
#cyfunc.pyx
from libcpp.string import string
from libcpp.vector import vector

cdef cfunc(vector[string] stringlist):
    cdef string s
    for s in stringlist:
        ...
        # do something with the strings

def func(stringlist):
    result = cfunc([s.encode('utf-8') for s in stringlist])
    return [s.decode('utf-8') for s in result]
```

However, as I don't actually need to do anything with the strings other than assert equality between them, I realised that I could probably elicit a speedup by ignoring the conversion step completely and just pass the Python strings as either `str` or `PyObject`:

```py
#cyfunc.pyx
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject

cdef cfunc(vector[PyObject] stringlist):
    cdef PyObject s
    for s in stringlist:
        ...
        # do something with the strings

def func(stringlist):
    return cfunc(stringlist)
```

But `str` makes the error "`Python object type 'unicode object' cannot be used as a template argument`" when trying to use it within `vector[`; and I'm having difficulties converting Python objects to `PyObject` ("`Cannot convert Python object to 'vector[PyObject]]`")

I imagine that eventually I'll have to define a new class for these strings with a custom comparison operator, because I don't imagine that asserting equality on PyObjects is meaningful, even if they're strings. In the meantime, though, what can I do to pass strings to Cython as Python objects?

Comment: So you can't use any kind of Python object in a C++ vector because the vector won't handle the reference counting correctly. But anyway, the structure of a hypothetical `vector[PyObject*]` is basically the same as the structure of a Python list (but without handling any reference counting), so why not just use a Python list?

Comment: @DavidW I'm looking to perform operations on the list with nogil, which requires that I use vectors and vector methods. I've got this working for `vector[string]` and now I just want to cut out the middle man.

Comment: There's (almost) nothing you can safely to do with Python objects without the GIL, therefore passing a vector of PyObject doesn't solve that problem. I think your best option would be to create a vector of `const char*` (initialized from the strings). Those pointers would only be valid while the strings exist (so you need to ensure that - don't try to store them for longer than a function call)

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "do something with the strings" in your code? Do you mean just looking up the lengths of the strings (which would be cached on the python side), iterating through the chars of a string, or mutating/modifying a string's contents?

Comment: I'm really looking to avoid the overhead of converting py3 unicode strings to bytes. If I can get away with just leaving them as the plain python objects, that's what I'm looking for. I'm doing 2 things with the strings: 1) adding them to another vector 2) checking if that vector already contains the string. This can be done with any object, so it really shouldn't matter that the objects in question here happen to be strings. At no point do I do anything string-unique. The only concern I have is that `"string" == "string"` but not necessarily `PyObject("string") == PyObject("string")`.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't just using python's 'set' ensure that you have only unique strings in your list? This could save the conversion from str to bytes for each item in the list, as well as the creation of an intermediate c++ vector.

Comment: No, because the provided example is a simplification of what I'm actually trying to achieve. The actual end result is a dict with tuple keys, where the members of that tuple are strings, and the value for each key is a dict with string keys, and value for each key of the inner dict is an int. The int is incremented whenever a series of strings matching the tuple is found in the provided list of strings. This is pretty much the same as a dict of `collections.Counter`s, but I've found that Counter is far too slow.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is: don't do this.

Cython is not designed for handling Python objects. If you are looking to speed up your Python application by throwing Python objects - including Python strings - at Cython, look elsewhere. You will find no speed increases here.

If you need to do string manipulation - even just string comparison - and you are using Python3 string objects, Cython is not your friend.